# I can't update and insert to sql server but I can select data

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I have some problem with update and insert data in sql server database BUT I can select data from it. I'm using visual studio 2012 , sql server 2012.

Please help ,Thank a lot.

This is my connectionstring in app.config

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;`enter code here`
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ProjectAppWIn
{
    public partial class Refill : Form
    {
        ProjectAppWIn.Login.user s;
        ProjectAppWIn.Home.userr r;
        public string sa;
        public string se;
        public Refill(ProjectAppWIn.Login.user s1, ProjectAppWIn.Home.userr s2)      //string user)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            s = s1;
            //  label2.Text = "Welcome  :  " + " " +   (user);
            sa = s.name;
            //on which control you want to show the username....
            label2.Text = "Welcome..." + s.name;

            r = s2;
            se = r.id;
            textBox8.Text = r.id + "";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

            Form targetform = new Login();
            targetform.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KHUNP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=kmuttssc;User ID=sa;Password=db2admin;"))
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.Contains("g") || textBox1.Text.Contains("G") == true)
                {
                    DataTable dte = new DataTable();
                    con1.Open();
                    SqlDataReader myRead = null;
                    //SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from card,user where card.card_id='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con1);
                    SqlCommand myCom = new SqlCommand("select card_balance,card_id from card  where guest_id = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con1);

                    myRead = myCom.ExecuteReader();

                    while (myRead.Read())
                    {
                        textBox6.Text = (myRead["card_balance"].ToString());
                        textBoxcardid.Text = (myRead["card_id"].ToString());

                        //TextBox8.Text = (myReader[].ToString());

                        //DropDownListGender.SelectedItem.Text = (myReader["gender"].ToString());
                        //DropDownListMonth.Text = (myReader["birth"].ToString());
                        //DropDownListYear.Text = (myReader["birth"].ToString());
                        //TextBoxAddress.Text = (myReader["address"].ToString());
                        //TextBoxCity.Text = (myReader["city"].ToString());
                        //DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.Text = (myReader["country"].ToString());
                        //TextBoxPostcode.Text = (myReader["postcode"].ToString());
                        //TextBoxEmail.Text = (myReader["email"].ToString());
                        //TextBoxCarno.Text = (myReader["carno"].ToString());
                    }
                    con1.Close();

                    //textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
                    //textBox7.Text = string.Empty;
                    // *****textBox8.Text = Session["id"] + "";
                }
                else
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    con1.Open();
                    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                    //SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from card,user where card.card_id='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con1);
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select u.user_id, u.user_fname, u.user_lname, c.user_id, c.card_balance,c.card_id from [user] u JOIN [card] c ON u.user_id = c.user_id where c.user_id = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con1);

                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        textBox6.Text = (myReader["card_balance"].ToString());
                        textBox2.Text = (myReader["user_fname"].ToString());
                        textBox3.Text = (myReader["user_lname"].ToString());
                        textBoxcardid.Text = (myReader["card_id"].ToString());

                    }

                    con1.Close();


                    textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
                    textBox7.Text = string.Empty;
                    label9.Text = string.Empty;
                    // ****textBox8.Text = Session["id"] + "";
                }//end using
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox7.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text)).ToString();
            using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KHUNP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=kmuttssc;User ID=sa;Password=db2admin;"))

                {
                    if (textBox1.Text.Contains("g") || textBox1.Text.Contains("G") == true)
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        con1.Open();
                        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                        //SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from card,user where card.card_id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con1);
                        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE card c join guest g on c.guest_id = g.guest_id SET c.card_balance = @card_balance,g.guest_status=@guest_status WHERE c.guest_id = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con1);
                        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@card_balance", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallInt);
                        //myCommand.Parameters.Add("@staff_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallInt);
                        myCommand.Parameters["@card_balance"].Value = textBox7.Text;
                        //myCommand.Parameters["@staff_id"].Value = textBox8.Text;
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guest_status", textBox9.Text);

                        //myCommand.Parameters["@staff_id"].Value = Session["];

                        try
                        {
                            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            //TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
                            //TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
                            //TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;
                            //TextBox5.Text = string.Empty;
                            //TextBox6.Text = string.Empty;


                            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KHUNP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=kmuttssc;User ID=sa;Password=db2admin;"))
                            {
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO transactionc (tranc_total, card_id,staff_id,date) VALUES (@tranc_total, @staff_id,@card_id, @date)");
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                cmd.Connection = conn;
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tranc_total", textBox5.Text);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@card_id", textBoxcardid.Text);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staff_id",textBox8.Text);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
                                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
                                conn.Open();
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }




                            label9.Text = "<b><big><big> Complete !!!</big></big> </b>";


                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            textBox7.Text = string.Empty;

                            label9.Text = "<b> <big> <big> Not Complete!!!</big> </big> </b>";
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            con1.Close();
                        }

                        //myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@card_balance", TextBox7.Text);
                        //myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        con1.Open();
                        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                        //SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from card,user where card.card_id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con1);
                        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE card set card_balance=@card_balance , WHERE user_id = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con1);
                        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@card_balance", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallInt);
                        //myCommand.Parameters.Add("@staff_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallInt);
                        myCommand.Parameters["@card_balance"].Value = textBox7.Text;
                        //myCommand.Parameters["@staff_id"].Value = textBox8.Text;
                        //myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guest_status", TextBox9.Text);

                        //myCommand.Parameters["@staff_id"].Value = Session["];

                        try
                        {
                            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            //TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
                            //TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
                            //TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;
                            //TextBox5.Text = string.Empty;
                            //TextBox6.Text = string.Empty;

                            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KHUNP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=kmuttssc;User ID=sa;Password=db2admin;"))
                            {
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO transactionc (tranc_total, card_id,staff_id, date) VALUES (@tranc_total, @card_id,@staff_id, @date)");
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                cmd.Connection = conn;
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tranc_total", textBox5.Text);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@card_id", textBoxcardid.Text);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staff_id", textBox8.Text);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
                                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
                                conn.Open();
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                            label9.Text = "<b><big><big> Complete !!!</big></big> </b>";


                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            textBox7.Text = string.Empty;

                            label9.Text = "<b> <big> <big> Not Complete!!!</big> </big> </b>";
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            con1.Close();
                        }



                }






            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form targetform = new Return(s, r);
            targetform.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form targetform = new Home1(s, r);
            targetform.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Does it die silently? How do you do your db calls? I think an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Comment: Do you get an error? If so what is the error message? Also the way you have structured this application is pretty horrible and un maintainable. You should give the controls names that are more meaningful than `textBox7` and `label9` and separate out the DB stuff from the UI stuff.

Comment: @RomanKo There's no error message, just can't update and insert

Comment: Change `catch` to `catch(Exception ex)` or set the breakpoint within the catch block and see what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to provide permission  to your user. Go to your database and execute the below query:-

```
USE [DBName]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'UserName'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'UserName'
```

There is one more approach to give the permsion which is by using the [GRANT privilage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188371.aspx).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what I should do.

Comment: @Khun'pCcm:- Go to the SQL Management Studio and execute the above query in your database and the username which you are using

Comment: It's error .
Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 35
User or role 'sa' does not exist in this database.
Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 35
User or role 'sa' does not exist in this database.

Comment: You may have installed SQL under a different user account, so your account does not have permissions to write. If you can, log on to your pc under that account and then use Management Studio to add a new user account (under Security in the folders on the left hand side). Add your own user account's name and give it datawriter or even sysadmin privileges. Then log back onto your account and you should be good to go.